# Return data in json after subscribe

Tags: service, promise, return, angular5, observers

I am using Angular 5 and want to return data from function getDionaeaResults in json format after subscribing to service

```
getDionaeaResults(sql) : any {
        this.dionaeaService.getDionaeaConnectionLogs(sql).subscribe(res => {
         this.data = res;
        }),
        (error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
        });
        return this.data;
    }
```

After calling this function, `this.totalAttacks` prints undefined.

```
getTotalAttack() {
       this.totalAttacks = this.getDionaeaResults("some query")
       console.log(this.totalAttacks,'attacks')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using the Obseravable .map() function.

```
getDionaeaResults(sql) : Observable<any> {
  return this.dionaeaService
             .getDionaeaConnectionLogs(sql)
             .map(res => res);
}

getTotalAttack(sql){
  this.getDionaeaResults("some query")
      .subscribe(
          res => { this.totalAttacks = res; },
          err => { console.log(err); }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.getDionaeaResults` is returning `undefined` because the service you're calling is asynchronous you have to wait for the subscribe callback. as Observables are asynchronous calls

```
this.data=res
```

might execute after the return statement. You can perhaps call that `dionaeaService` directly inside `getTotalAttack()` function, like this:

```
getTotalAttack(sql){
   this.dionaeaService.getDionaeaConnectionLogs(sql).subscribe(res => {
      this.totalAttacks = res;
    }),
    (error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
    });
 }
```

Comment: I am using `this.getDionaeaResults` function as a universal, which can be call from any function by passing sql querry and will get the results in json, plus I  am returning the data in `this.getDionaeaResults` after the subscribe call.